# PHP Namespaces with fatal error

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm developing a project but I can't seem to get the namespaces to work.

I have the following structure:

src folder:

```
- Searcher.php
- execSearch.php
```

In the Searcher.php file ( that represents the Searcher class ) I have the following line:

```
namespace search\Searcher;
```

and in execSearch.php I try to use the namespace like this:

```
use search\Searcher\Searcher;
```

I also tried.

```
use search\Searcher;
```

but with no success, I always get the same error:

```
Fatal Error: Class 'search\Searcher\Searcher' not found in searchExec.php
```

I also defined in my composer.json file the following:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "search\\Searcher\\": "src"
    }
}
```

How can use the namespaces correctly so I can use the class in execSearch.php?

Answer (score 0):

With `PSR-4` you must place your `search\Searcher\Searcher` class in the file `src\search\Searcher\Searcher.php`.

So your tree looks like this:

```
composer.json
src/
   execSearch.php    (or searchExec.php?)
   search/
     Searcher/
       Searcher.php
```

Comment: so I need a folder 'src' on top of the others?

Comment: The composer.json PSR configuration says to look for files in `"src"`, so I assumed when you said `src folder` your PHP files were in `src/`...